# Linq to Entities - Conversion of data types inside lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Iam trying to get all the employees info so that i can bind the list of employees to a dropdown, i need the Employee id and Employee name but both these are present different tables...

I have created a Employee class with EmployeeId and EmployeeName as properties.

```
public List<Employee> empDetails()
{
  List<Employee> emps = new List<Employee>();
  emps = EMPDB.Employees.AsNoTracking().select(s => new Employee()
  {
  EmployeeId = s.EmpId,
  Name = EMPDB.EmployeeNames.Where( a => a.EmployeeId == convert.tostring(s.EmpId)).select(a => a.DisplayName).FirstOrDefault();
  }
}).ToList();
```

The issue is we are not supposed to use convert.tostring() here in lambda expression, where as in 1 table EmployeeId is of type string, where as in another table the EmpId is of type long.

Comment: Are you really using C# version 4? That is very, very, old (it was released in 2010...)

Comment: not c# version 4, i have edited

Comment: Anyway, don't try to convert data type like this. Just make both models use an integer.

Comment: @user3198688 why don't you use simple join between table to get id and name?

Comment: changing the datatype on the table makes our work a bit complex, is it not possible to do without changing the data type ?

Comment: Fix the problem now, or it will just get more complicated in the future.

Comment: "we are not supposed to use convert.tostring() here in lambda expression" - what does that mean exactly? The two types cannot be compared, what are you expected to do?